# Does Sandboxie slow down the system?

Tags: rendering, video-editing, sandbox, sandboxie

I'm currently working with many video editing programs, which have conflicts with their components (Pinnacle, Avid, Premiere, Corel Video Studio, and others).

Could [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com) slow down my workflow or the rendering process if I use one of those programs inside a "[SandBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security))"?

I think when I use many "memory hungry" programs, my system could slow down. I also know Adobe Premiere is possibly the best, but I just want to know if using Sandboxie could affect my work.

Comment: I had no idea sandboxie had a purpose other than for surfing suspicious websites...

Answer (score 2):

Sandboxie could considerably slow down your rendering process.

From their FAQ:

> Why are so many files copied into the sandbox?
>
> When a program accesses a file, it declares what operations it plans
>   to do on the file: if it plans to read from the file, to write the
>   file, to change its attributes, and so on. Whenever a program declares
>   any kind of write access to a file, Sandboxie copies it into the
>   sandbox. In some cases, programs declare they intend to write to the
>   file when in fact they do not, but nevertheless Sandboxie must copy
>   the file into the sandbox.

So it is more of a case by case basis, since it is unpredictable whether Sandboxie will copy a file into the Sandbox or not for any given application.